# Record inserted failed in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi i am getting the problem of adding the record in to the database.when i insert the record into the database. message display record insert failed. i double checked the coding and programming syntax all were fine.but i didn't get any errors while was running what was the problem. can some one fix the problem do get the error. exception handing also i have put but unfortunate it doens't help for me to display the error.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $bassname = $_POST['bassname'];
    $cat      = $_POST['cat'];

    $p_img1 = $_FILES['p_img1']['name'];
    $p_img2 = $_FILES['p_img2']['name'];
    $p_img3 = $_FILES['p_img3']['name'];

    $temp_name1 = $_FILES['p_img1']['tmp_name'];
    $temp_name2 = $_FILES['p_img2']['tmp_name'];
    $temp_name3 = $_FILES['p_img3']['tmp_name'];

    move_uploaded_file($temp_name1, "product_images/$p_img1");
    move_uploaded_file($temp_name2, "product_images/$p_img2");
    move_uploaded_file($temp_name3, "product_images/$p_img3");

    $mobile     = $_POST['mobile'];
    $address    = $_POST['address'];
    $job_desc   = $_POST['job_desc'];
    $work_video = $_POST['work_video'];

    $insert_product = "insert into 
                bass_registation(
                    bassname,
                    category,
                    job_image1,
                    job_image2,
                    job_image3,
                    mobile,
                    address,
                    job_des,
                    video
                ) values (
                    '$bassname',
                    '$cat',
                    '$p_img1',
                    '$p_img2',
                    '$p_img3',
                    '$mobile',
                    '$address',
                    '$job_desc',
                    '$work_video'
                )";

    $run_product    = mysqli_query($con, $insert_product);

    try {
        if ($run_product) {
            echo "<script>alert('Data has been inserted successfully')</script>";
        } else {
            echo "<script>alert('Data has been Failed')</script>";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Message: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Standard Debug - 1. perform a var_dump($_POST) and check the values... ( You are not performing any validation) 2. Add in an echo $insert_product; to view the SQL and run it in phpmyadmin or whatever SQL program you use to test the SQL... 3. Learn how to perform validation of your POST values and perform safer SQL operations...

Comment: when i put echo $insert_product; all values are assigned correctly see below.but data insert failed
insert into bass_registation(bassname,category,job_image1,job_image2,job_image3,mobile,address,job_des,video) values ('john','2','1.jpg','','','80033322222','london',' 1 year','youtube ')

Comment: Ok, so did you run it against your database using the SQL in phpmyadmin or whatever you use to manually run SQL statements on your database?

Comment: i am running using phpmyadmin database. connect as localhost

Comment: So what happens when copy and paste that sql command you echoed out ( shown in your comment above ) into phpmyadmin?

Comment: $run_product    = mysqli_query($con, $insert_product); at this point something getting error sir. above all data has been passing successfully

Comment: phpmyadmin has an SQL Tab in it you can test out your SQL in... So Please, Copy and paste your SQL in it - and Click on GO to run it... This will at least test your SQL is working or not...

Comment: So did that help? Did you get it worked out?

Comment: yes sir you are always best